# building QT with debug information for MSVS 2010 using jom

Tags: visual-studio, qt, build, visual-studio-debugging

I am trying to use QT libraries in an open source application.
I have downloaded the source files for QT, and then tried to build it using jom.
First in the

```
C:\QT\4.8.2
```

I ran this:

```
configure -debug-and-release -opensource -platform win32-msvc2010
```

and then I ran this command:

```
..\jom\jom.exe -j 2
```

For a reference I followed steps suggested in:

http://www.holoborodko.com/pavel/2011/02/01/how-to-compile-qt-4-7-with-visual-studio-2010

Now when I try to debug my project in MSVS2010 I get this error (in debug mode):

```
qtmain.lib(qtmain_win.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2' in audiomixerboard.obj
```

It looks like QT was not built with debug info.
Does anyone have an idea of what is wrong and what should I do?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your APP is seem built in release mode. Because qtmain.lib is for release, and qtmaind.lib is for debug. Debug library is named end with 'd'.

Comment: thanks for the answer. In the MSVS 2010 there is a drop down window that I can choose how to build, and I chose "Debug" (the options are: Debug, Release, and VST Release). Isn't that enough to build the APP in debug mode?

Comment: Thanks that was a great clue that helped to resolve it. I replaced qtmain.lib with qtmainq.lib in the linker setting and it resolved it.